# Google Analytics API - Is there a way to block under 18s to view my website?

Tags: api, analytics

Local law states that under 18s should not access my financial website. Is there a way I can use Google Analytics API to determine age and redirect users to a third party domain explaining the law?

This script, if possible will need to run in the header and execute before page load.

I understand that people using incognito will still get through, and that's fine.

I have tried using popups but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Google Analytics API - Is there a way to block under 18s to view my website?

No. That is not a feature available in Google Analytics.

> I understand that people using incognito will still get through, and that's fine.

I doubt that. Most laws requiring that something does not permit minors access require that the person's age is verified. i.e. "Over 18s only" and *not* "Over 18s and people we don't know the age of only".

Comment: Sure, that's the intention, but for the remaining we have popups to warn them that the content is not suitable for under 18s. Unless you have a better idea to judge the age without having that information.

Comment: @AS "Unless you have a better idea to judge the age without having that information" -- You should not be asking random strangers on the Internet about this. Ask your lawyer.

Comment: I don't know the specific requirements of the unspecified law in the unspecified geographical location you are talking about

Comment: Ask my lawyer how to determine age of an ip address on my website?

Comment: I appreciate your help Quentin.

Comment: Ask your lawyer what the specific requirements of the law are, and what methods of age verification were accepted / rejected in any case law relating to it.

Comment: @Quentin all I need to know is if Analytics can do what I need done. You said it can't be done, for which I'm thankful. If you must insist on the law, please read [link](https://ico.org.uk/media/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/children-and-the-gdpr-1-0.pdf)

Comment: @AS — If you don't want responses to your follow ups then don't ask follow ups.

Comment: This shouldn't require stating, but IP addresses don't have ages.

Comment: @JonathanHall you win sir.